# Special characters in data declaration

Tags: haskell

From the following article [Inductive Graphs and Functional Graph Algorithms](https://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~erwig/papers/InductiveGraphs_JFP01.pdf), the data is defined as follows

```
type Node = Int
type Adj b = [(b, Node)]
type Context a b = (Adj b, Node, a, Adj b)

data Graph a b = Empty | Context a b & Graph a b
```

where `&` is an infix operator.

I tried replicating it as follows

```
data Graph a b = Empty | (&) (Context a b) (Graph a b) deriving Show
```

But I can't seem to print it

```
*Main> (&) ([], 3, 'c',[]) Empty

<interactive>:124:1: error:
    Variable not in scope:
      (&) :: ([t0], Integer, Char, [t1]) -> Graph a0 b0 -> t
```

How would I use non-alphabetic characters in a data declaration? And is it possible to make it an infix operator?

Comment: It's been a while since I read that paper, but from my memory: it's probably worth noting that the `Graph` definition you give is just a conceptual one. It's to help you understand the intended behavior of the various "pattern-matching" like combinators, not an actual implementation. It would have terrible performance for just about everything you want to do with graphs, so a more intricate data type is used internally, and an interface that behaves as if it had that data definition is exposed externally.

Comment: @DanielWagner how would I import FGL package from Hackage? I did `cabal install fgl` and `cabal info fgl` indeed showed modules such as `Data.Graph.Inductive.Graph` but if I import in a .hs file, I get `Failed to load interface`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Non-infix constructors must start with an Uppercase letter. Infix constructors must start with `:`.

```
data Graph a b = Empty | (:&) (Context a b) (Graph a b) deriving Show
```

or

```
data Graph a b = Empty | Context a b :& Graph a b deriving Show
```

To be pedantic: there are some exceptions (`[]`, `(,)`, ...) but only among basic primitives, so they do not matter when defining `data` types.

Comment: How come ghc would compile fine with `(&) (Context a b) (Graph a b)`?

Comment: And how would you make it right-associative? UPDATE: found solution `infixr 7 :&`

Comment: @phoxd `(&)` is a valid infix function name, but not a valid data constructor name.